# what is reader.getPageRotation() in iTextSharp.text.pdf

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

i am trying to merge two PDF documents. when i looking for sample codes, some of those contain GetPageRotation() function. what is meant by GetPageRotation() function or what action is take place when we call this function?

Comment: Please remove the pdfbox label, as this question isn't about pdfbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPageRotation(int index)

It gets the page rotation.

I have find all methods & Description of itextpdf.text.pdf on [itextsupport.com](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html)

Answer (score 0):

The page size is defined in user units. For instance: an A4 page measures 595 x 842 user units. There are different ways to define the orientation. If you want to change a portrait page to a landscape page, you could switch the width and the height: 842 x 595. However, that's not very elegant. It's much better to set the page rotation. As defined in ISO-32000, there are 4 possible values for the page rotation: 0, 90, 180, 270. See also: [iTextSharp how to rotate/switch page from landscape to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345067/itextsharp-how-to-rotate-switch-page-from-landscape-to-portrait)

However, if you want to merge two document, you shouldn't worry about the page rotation. The `PdfCopy` and `PdfSmartCopy` class takes care of getting the page rotation correctly. If you really need `GetPageRotation()` to merge two PDF files, then you are doing it wrong. See [How to merge documents correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731439/how-to-merge-documents-correctly)